# the references are not working in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I was creating a website on a laptop and everything was fine, but when I sent my project and started working on it in another laptop, non of the references worked
What can I do to make them work again?

Comment: Have you made sure that the necessary .net framework/core versions are installed on the second machine? Are you using the same version of Visual Studio on both machines?

Comment: yes, I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on both of them ... how can I check if "the necessary .net framework/core versions are installed "?

Comment: Check in VS what version of .Net the project(s) are targetting, then check whether that version is installed on your PC.

Comment: my project target framework is .Net Frame work 4.6.1 and it's installed on my PC

Comment: So, which references aren't "working"

Comment: All of them aren't working and have a yellow warning triangle on them and when I try to open them it says "This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built"

Comment: thank you phuzi for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

non of the references worked no matter what I did.
then I opened a new project and copied every thing I had in the old one , and then all of the references worked.